Why can't this laravel collection sort its index by time?
My objective is to optionally filter a list of attendances, sorting the employees by which of them comes the earliest or latest in a given period of time. My logic for going about this is:

grouping attendance by each day
rank each attendance by how early/late, depending on parameter, using their index on the sorted list
sum their indexes to find the highest value in each case

The problem now is that, the same attendances always carry same index, irrespective of sorting algorithm used i.e. earliest always carries 0. Sorting the list simply pushes the element to the bottom of the list visually, but it still bears 0, which makes no sense
The code I originally had was
protected function punctualChart ($attendanceCollection, ?string $puncMode) {

        $puncMode = $puncMode?? "ear";
        // group them into each day. rank by employee with most days
        $attendanceDays = $attendanceCollection->groupBy(function ($attendance) {

            return $attendance->created_at->format("m-d");
        })
        ->map(function ($daysCollection) use ($puncMode) { // then sum their value for each day? add their indexes. depending on the mode, we know whether highest or lowest is the winner

            return $daysCollection->sort(function ($a, $b) use ($puncMode) {

                $date1 = $a->created_at;

                $date2 = $b->created_at;

                if ($puncMode == "lat") {

                    if ($b > $a) return 1;

                    if ($a > $b) return -1;

                    return 0;
                }
                else {

                    if ($a > $b) return 1;

                    if ($b > $a) return -1;

                    return 0;
                }
            });
        })->values();
        // dd($attendanceDays->get(1), $attendanceDays->get(2), $puncMode);
        $scoreEmployee = [];

        foreach ($attendanceDays as $attendanceCollection) {

            foreach ($attendanceCollection as $index => $attendance) {
                dump($index);
                $employeeId = /*$attendance->employee->last_name.*/$attendance->employee_id;

                if (!array_key_exists($employeeId, $scoreEmployee))

                    $scoreEmployee[$employeeId] = /*0;*/[

                        "value" => 0,

                        "model" => $attendance->employee->last_name
                    ];

                $scoreEmployee[$employeeId]["value"] += $index+1; // offset 0-based index
            }
        }

        $sortedEmployeeScores = 
        \Illuminate\Support\Arr::sort($scoreEmployee, "value");
        dd($scoreEmployee, $sortedEmployeeScores);

        return $scoreEmployee;
    }

It was subsequently simplified to
protected function punctualChart ($attendanceCollection, ?string $puncMode) {

        $puncMode = $puncMode?? "ear";
// group them into each day. rank by employee with most days
        $attendanceDays = $attendanceCollection->groupBy(function ($attendance) {

            return $attendance->created_at->format("m-d");
        })
        ->map(function ($daysCollection) use ($puncMode) { // then sum their value for each day? add their indexes. depending on the mode, we know whether highest or lowest is the winner

            return $puncMode == "ear"? $daysCollection->sortBy("created_at"):

            $daysCollection->sortByDesc("created_at");
        })/*->values()*/;
// dd($attendanceDays->get(1), $attendanceDays->get(2), $puncMode);
        $scoreEmployee = [];

        foreach ($attendanceDays as $attendanceCollection) {

            foreach ($attendanceCollection as $index => $attendance) {
dump($index);
                $employeeId = /*$attendance->employee->last_name.*/$attendance->employee_id;

                if (!array_key_exists($employeeId, $scoreEmployee))

                    $scoreEmployee[$employeeId] = /*0;*/[

                        "value" => 0,

                        "model" => $attendance->employee->last_name
                    ];

                $scoreEmployee[$employeeId]["value"] += $index+1; // offset 0-based index
            }
        }

        $sortedEmployeeScores = \Illuminate\Support\Arr::sort($scoreEmployee, "value");
dd($scoreEmployee, $sortedEmployeeScores);
        return $scoreEmployee;
    }

From where I realized the sorting is unnecessary. Funny enough, the results are auto sorted. However, that indexing is fixed and unable to be altered. Whatever the case may be, same elements always have same indexes. So I thought maybe, reversing the list would help i.e. instead of passing puncMode, I'll just reverse the array to obtain the inverse. But that doesn't work either
So what am I doing wrong and how do I swap their indexes to reflect their position? Then sum this position for rendering on my chart (you don't need to add this part. Just revealing for the sake of completion)?

I tweaked the code slightly with the following inclusions:

Rejigged sorted data indexes by returning values(), instead of the collection as-is
It made more sense to average the scores in either mode, since the indices don't make much sense to the viewer. It provides greater clarity into what the ranking is all about. I compared returned result set with the actual row values and the ranking for the employees in each mode checks out

In addition, the sorting function is not entirely redundant as earlier assumed, since the behavior varies, depending on incoming parameter. The current sort implementation is more concise and less error-prone than the one in my earlier draft
So, putting it all together, we have:
protected function punctualChart ($attendanceCollection, ?string $puncMode) {

        $puncMode = $puncMode?? "ear";

        $attendanceDays = $attendanceCollection->groupBy(function ($attendance) {

            return $attendance->created_at->format("m-d");
        })
        ->map(function ($daysCollection) use ($puncMode) { // then sum their value for each day? add their indexes. depending on the mode, we know whether highest or lowest is the winner

            return $puncMode == "ear"? $daysCollection->sortByDesc("created_at")->values():

            $daysCollection->sortBy("created_at")->values();
        });
//dd($attendanceDays, $puncMode);
        $scoreEmployee = [];

        $maxValue = 0;

        foreach ($attendanceDays as $attendanceCollection) {

            foreach ($attendanceCollection as $index => $attendance) {

                $employeeId = /*$attendance->employee->last_name.*/$attendance->employee_id;

                if (!array_key_exists($employeeId, $scoreEmployee))

                    $scoreEmployee[$employeeId] = /*0;*/[

                        "value" => 0,

                        "model" => $attendance->employee, //->last_name
                    ];

                $maxValue += $index+1;

                $scoreEmployee[$employeeId]["value"] += $index+1; // offset 0-based index
            }
        }

        foreach ($scoreEmployee as $employeeId => &$employeeDetails)

            $employeeDetails["value"] = round(

                ($employeeDetails["value"]/$maxValue)*100,

                2
            );
//dd($scoreEmployee);
        return $scoreEmployee;
    }

Thanks to @angel for motivating me to give this another shot

reassign the indexes to the resulting collection


If Angel's advice was helpful, you are meant to upvote it, not say thank you in an answer.

@mickmackusa I thought about that, and felt a little guilty. But he didn't post any code sample. The difference between his suggestion and modifications I had to make is still substantial. I mentioned him in my answer to show I value his effort in attempting to assist

The problem seems to be with how you're handling the indexes during the iteration over the attendance collection. The index you get with the foreach loop corresponds to the position of the element in the original collection, not necessarily reflecting the order you'd expect after sorting.
The solution you can apply is to reassign the indexes after sorting, so they reflect the new position of each attendance. Here’s a simple fix for you:
After grouping and sorting the attendances, reassign the indexes to the resulting collection. Make sure the indexes reflect the new order, whether it's sorted by earliest or latest.

Is this a Model? or Controller? if so, Apply Scopes on Model, and use Query Builder, for more code readability and reusability.


it's in a controller/service. 2) I strongly discourage the use of those funny, implicit, "magic" eloquent methods. The content of the method may be more readable cuz of $this, but it sucks at discoverability. Avoid at all costs. 3) the issue at hand can't be solved at the db layer. How do you suppose you can group, sort, sum and average? Even if that were possible, it would be too convoluted to maintain


Should this "answer" be a comment?
